# How to generate series between the min and max timestamps of two tables (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

I have two tables with weather data that are frequently updated. Table A has data with 10 min interval and table B with 1 hour interval.

**Table A (realized weather)**

| observationtime | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 17/02/21 00:00 | 9 |
| 17/02/21 00:10 | 9 |
| 17/02/21 00:20 | 9 |
| 17/02/21 00:30 | 9 |
| ... | ... |
| 17/02/21 03:00 | 9 |

**Table B (weather forecast)**

| observationtime | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 17/02/21 04:00 | 9 |
| 17/02/21 05:00 | 9 |
| 17/02/21 06:00 | 9 |
| 17/02/21 07:00 | 9 |

What I want

| observationtime | realized_temperature | forecasted_temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17/02/21 00:00 | 9 |  |
| 17/02/21 01:00 | 9 |  |
| 17/02/21 02:00 | 9 |  |
| 17/02/21 03:00 | 9 |  |
| 17/02/21 04:00 |  | 9 |
| 17/02/21 05:00 |  | 9 |
| 17/02/21 06:00 |  | 9 |
| 17/02/21 07:00 |  | 9 |

So as far as I can gather three things need to happen:

- First I need to get the smallest timestamp from table A and round it down the smallest whole hour
- Get the max timestamp from the forecast table
- Generate a series between these two timestamps with 1 hour intervals
- Join Table A and B on the generated series

Can't quite figure out how to do this. Anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `generate_series()` as I see it:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8f0e87c1d6a4f127d310194886f8de75)

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(r.observationtime, fc.observationtime) as observationtime,     -- 3
    r.temperature as realized_temperature,
    fc.temperature as forecasted_temperature
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('hour', observationtime))                -- 1
        *
    FROM r
    ORDER BY date_trunc('hour', observationtime), observationtime
) r
FULL JOIN fc ON r.observationtime = fc.observationtime                      -- 2
ORDER BY 1
```

1. First extract every first record per hour from the `realized` table. This can be done using `DISTINCT ON` which returns the first record of an ordered group. Here your group is the hour (with `date_trunc()` you can convert the `hh:10` - `hh:50` values to the full hour to join the group).
2. Use a `FULL JOIN`: This joins the tables even if there are no matching timestamps
3. Use `COALESCE()` to return the first non-`NULL` value in the list. So, if there is `realized` temperature, this will be taken, otherwise the forecasted.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Awesome explanation!

Yes, it solved the issue. Thank you!

However, sometimes there may be a small overlap in the observed temperature and the forecast. Is there a way to implement this so the realized temperature and forecasted temperature columns are continous? Can't draw a line graph for all of the data if the data in not continous... I suppose it works with scatter plot as well though. :)

Comment: I have no quick idea for that. I believe, doing some roundings may help.